# What should be my arguments in my function and what should i return

Tags: python-3.x, return, arguments

I have a simple question in Python. Write a program that asks the user to enter a password.

If the user enters the right password, the program should tell them they are logged in to the system.

Otherwise, the program should ask them to reenter the password. The user should only get five tries to enter the password, after which point the program should tell them that they are kicked off of the system.

I have already done the problem, but I don't know if I need arguments in my function. Another question is what should i return in the program. I put return 0 but I don't want the 0 to appear in the debugger.

```
def code():
    global password
    password='123456'
    global total_guesses
    total_guesses=5
    while total_guesses<=5 and total_guesses>0:
        resposta=input('Digite password\n')
        if password==resposta:
            print('You have entered the system')
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong password you haver',total_guesses,'total_guesses')
            total_guesses-=1
    return 0
print(code())
```

Comment: You can for sure parametrize password and total_guesses, and decide in whether to return a value or not based on some conditions! @Luismaia1994

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any arguments... you also don't need to return anything, the function will exit when it finishes.

Comment: but if i dont put return it says none in the debugger

Comment: is that an issue?

Comment: it does that because the function implicitly returns `None` when it completes

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `password` and `total_guesses` as an input to the function if you want those to be user-controlled.

Also it is up to you if you want to return something or not, you can return `True` if the password is correct, otherwise return `False`, if you want to make further decisions based on those values, e.g if the user logs in, open a UI, or if the user cannot log in, shut the program etc. Or you can return nothing, it is upto your next step after the user logs in/fails to log in

```
def code(password, total_guesses):

    #Flag to return if user logged in or not
    logged_in = False
    while total_guesses<=5 and total_guesses>0:
        resposta=input('Digite password\n')
        if password==resposta:
            print('You have entered the system')
            logged_in = True
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong password you haver',total_guesses,'total_guesses')
            total_guesses-=1

    #Return the flag        
    return logged_in

password='123456'
total_guesses=5

#Use password and total_guesses as inputs
print(code(password, total_guesses))
```

The outputs will look like

```
Digite password
123456
You have entered the system
True

Digite password
1
Wrong password you haver 5 total_guesses
Digite password
2
Wrong password you haver 4 total_guesses
Digite password
3
Wrong password you haver 3 total_guesses
Digite password
4
Wrong password you haver 2 total_guesses
Digite password
5
Wrong password you haver 1 total_guesses
False
```